# sorting a list by key then value in python

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list whose keys is the date and the value is the hour of that day a sample looks like this

```
dtlist = [{'26/12/2010','01'},{'27/3/2008','00'},{'7/7/2007','10'},{'7/7/2007','23'}]
```

The output that I should get is

```
dtlist= [{'7/7/2007','10'},{'7/7/2007','23'},{'27/3/2008','00'},{'26/12/2010','01'}]
```

I want the date to be sorted by year, month, day and when the date is the same sort by hour in increasing order. Many thanks.

Comment: That isn't a valid `Dictionary` because a `Dictionary` has unique keys.

Comment: yes of course. A list is what I have I'll edit.

Comment: And what language is this?  I think I may have been under the impression is was .NET previously but now I see that there's no indication that that's the case.

Comment: it is in python sorry. I am so new to stack exchange I thought everything here was in python.

Comment: What you show is a list of sets, not of dicts.

Comment: Also lists don't have the concept of keys and values.  Try to give us a little bit of real code - that way we can be more confident in the details of your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of unordered set litterals. I'm assuming you actually want to use something else, like a list of lists, or a list of tuples.

Here's how you can do it with a list of lists, or a list of tuples:

```
a = [['26/12/2010','01'],['27/3/2008','00'],['7/7/2007','10'],['7/7/2007','23']]

def k(a):
    d = list(map(int, a[0].split("/")))
    return d[::-1] + [int(a[1])]

print(sorted(a, key=k))
```

outputs:
    [['7/7/2007', '10'], ['7/7/2007', '23'], ['27/3/2008', '00'], ['26/12/2010', '01']]

The `key` function returns the key for an item in the list, which is then used by the sorting function to sort the list.

In this example your input data corresponds to these keys:

```
items: [['7/7/2007', '10'], ['7/7/2007', '23'], ['27/3/2008', '00'], ['26/12/2010', '01']]
keys:  [[2007, 7, 7, 10],   [2007, 7, 7, 23],   [2008, 3, 27, 0],    [2010, 12, 26, 1]]
```

We thus sort by year, followed by month, followed by day, and lastly hour.